# proof of diamond lemma

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, logic, algorithms, combinatorial-group-theory

I am trying to prove the diamond lemma: Suppose we have two elementary cancellations of a word
$w$

[image]

then there exists some $w'$ such that there are (possibly trivial) cancellations

[image]

The diamond lemma,

[image]

There are two cases to consider: whether or not the cancelled subwords in $w$ overlap.

How can I write the proof in the case that the cancelled subwords overlap?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: By elementary cancellation, do you mean cancelling a single letter?

Comment: It would be helpful here if you clarified that the question is about *free* cancellation, and that "elementary cancellation" means a single letter.

Answer (score 2):

If the cancellations $aa^{-1}$ and $bb^{-1}$ overlap then either:

1. The occurrences of $aa^{-1}, bb^{-1}$ are the same word, so $w=paa^{-1}q=pbb^{-1}q$ and $w_1=pq=w_2$.
2. If the occurrences of $aa^{-1}, bb^{-1}$ overlap but are non-equal then $w=paa^{-1}aq$, where $a^{-1}a=bb^{-1}$ (i.e. $a=b^{-1}$ and $a^{-1}=b$), and we have
   $$
   paq=w_1\xleftarrow{aa^{-1}}w\xrightarrow{a^{-1}a}w_2=paq.
   $$

In both cases, we have that $w_1=w_2$, and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** See [Newman's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newman%27s_lemma): That is a relation is confluent (satisfies the diamond property) if and only if it is [locally confluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_(abstract_rewriting)#Local_confluence).